# as3 functions how dyname movieclip name?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I give this a dynamic name. I know this is simple but going from as2 to as3.

```
function Love(mc:MovieClip):void
{   
    var loadit = new Loader();
    loadit.load(new URLRequest(mc));
    addChild(loadit);
}

Love(one);
```

How do I change the "one" and "mc" to work?

thanks

Comment: A function name should not start with an uppercase letter. Take a looks at the AS3 Coding Conventions: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions#CodingConventions-Methodnames Unless of course "Love" is the contructor.

Comment: @Adam Harte : camelCasing is the standard for coding convention. But not must be.

Comment: May I know. Why do you used loader class?

Answer (score 0):

In AS3 you don't really use the "name" of the movieclip anymore. You just store a reference to the instance.

I am not really sure what you are trying to do with your code. You Love method take a movieclip instance, but then you pass that reference to the new URLRequest constructor. But the URLRequest take a String. Have a look at the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#URLRequest%28%29) if you get stuck.

Comment: Why is as3 so ridiculously hard compared to as2? So frustrating.

Comment: @ed.vizenor It is not hard once you have a basic understanding of how OOP works. I imagin from your comment, that you only really scratched the surface of what AS2 can do, and you probably never when further that timeline scripts. Maybe you need to start from the start with AS3. There are loads of questions on SO asking where to begin with AS3 and OOP.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get u completely at what u looking for, I've just added some coding.. just go through it.

```
var my_mc:MovieClip =  new MovieClip();

function Love(mc:MovieClip):void
{   
    //var loadit = new Loader();
    //loadit.load(new URLRequest(mc));
    this.my_mc = mc;
    addChild(my_mc);
    my_mc.x = my_mc.y  = 10;
    trace("called");
}

Love(one);// one is timeline based MC.
```